# How to get click on selected FancyTree node to activate again?

Tags: fancytree

If I click on my fancytree menu nodes they activate dialog boxes that appear next to the menu. These have cancel buttons that make the dialog close. However, when I click on the same menu item (node) again the same dialog box does not appear again (as I want it to), I think because Fancytree thinks it's the currently selected node so ignores it.

If I click on a different menu item instead, it works fine and the dialog box for that one appears. So how do I get Fancytree to fire the same `activate:` function for the currently selected menu item when it's clicked again?

In my cancel button handler I tried using `node.setSelected(false)` which should deselect the item, but still the dialog box does not re-appear when I click the same item again. I've confirmed that it's the correct (current) node that setSelected(false) is used on.

I'm just using a standard fancytree config, e.g. the following:

```
var currentMenuItemNode;

$("#tree").fancytree({
    activate: function(event, data){
        this.currentMenuItemNode = data.node;
    }
});

cancelButtonHandler() {
  // Close dialog box here

  this.currentMenuItemNode.setSelected(false); // Deselect item
}
```

Any thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `activate` event is not fired if a node is already active, so the [click event](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialEvents#howto-find-out-source-and-the-clicked-region-in-a-click-handler) might be what you're looking for:

```js
$("#tree").fancytree({
  [...]
  click: function(event, data) {
    var node = data.node,
        // Only for click and dblclick events:
        // 'title' | 'prefix' | 'expander' | 'checkbox' | 'icon'
        targetType = data.targetType;

    // we could return false to prevent default handling, i.e. generating
    // activate, expand, or select events
  },
});
```